# Change Z-Index On Click Using AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a navigation bar with four items and some icons related to each menu item. The icons are positioned absolutely one behind another and they being loaded to the view from different template but in the scope of the same controller.

What I am trying to achieve is to change z-index of the icon based on the clicked menu item using angular. I tried several methods using ng-switch for example but cannot figure out due to lack of experience.

Could you please share you ideas on how to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

HTML

Header View:

```
<nav id="top-nav">
    <ul>
        <li ui-sref="root.home";>Home</li>
        <li ui-sref="root.drinks">Drinks</li>
        <li ui-sref="root.food-and-snacks">Food And Snacks</li>
        <li ui-sref="root.contacts">Contacts</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Icons View:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home Icon</li>
    <li>Drinks Icon</li>
    <li>Food Icon</li>
    <li>Contacts Icon</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    lefT: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using ng-class? You can create a class with the z-index you desire to assign, then apply that class with ui-router. For example: .super-zindex {z-index: 999} for the class, then ng-class="{super-zindex: $state.includes('home')}"; if this works for you, let me know and I'll make it an answer so others can see it.

Comment: Thanks for your respone. The problem is that I cannot use includes as the icons are already displayed when the page loads. I will explain in more details: once page is loaded users see four icons, on click to any of them, all four icons animate to left top corner with the one clicked on higher index. Behind the icons, users see related to the icon. And the loaded view I have another menu to let users navigate though other pages.

Comment: If you are unable to use a class you can create a custom directive to handle a click event and set the z-index programmatically inside of that event handler.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is the only solution for now. I just thought that there is something more elegant :) Thanks for answers anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I implemented the Z-Index change on-click:

HTML

```
<ul class="icons">
    <li ng-class="{front:ctrl.activeTab(1)}">icon1</li>
    <li ng-class="{front:ctrl.activeTab(2)}">icon2</li>
    <li ng-class="{front:ctrl.activeTab(3)}">icon3</li>
    <li ng-class="{front:ctrl.activeTab(4)}">icon4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav">
    <li ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(1)">menu item1</li>
    <li ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(2)">menu item2</li>
    <li ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(3)">menu item3</li>
    <li ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(4)">menu item4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.icons li.front{
z-index:1;
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
self.selectTab = function (id) {
    self.tab = id;
}
self.activeTab = function (id) {
    return self.tab === id;
}
```